# Angular 12 - NgMaterialMultilevelMenuModule - Display problem

Tags: angular, angular-module

(Sorry in advance if the tags are bad)

I'm trying to use the NgMaterialMultilevelMenuModule in order to do a multi-level menu (logic). I found tutorials but what ever I do, it shows nothing and after I call the module and it doesn't show what is after in the html file (I only see "Menu"). I copied/pasted the example code, did I miss something ? I'm quite new with angular.

Thanks in advance

The .html of the componant:

```
<p>Menu</p>

<ng-material-multilevel-menu  
    [configuration]='config' 
    [items]='appitems'
    (selectedItem)="selectedItem($event)">
</ng-material-multilevel-menu>

<p> test </p>
```

The .ts of the componant:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-menu-donnees',
  templateUrl: './menu-donnees.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./menu-donnees.component.css']
})
export class MenuDonneesComponent {

  appitems = [
    {
      label: 'Item 1 (with Font awesome icon)',
      faIcon: 'fab fa-500px',
      items: [
        {
          label: 'Item 1.1',
          link: '/item-1-1',
          faIcon: 'fab fa-accusoft'
        },
        {
          label: 'Item 1.2',
          faIcon: 'fab fa-accessible-icon',
          items: [
            {
              label: 'Item 1.2.1',
              link: '/item-1-2-1',
              faIcon: 'fas fa-allergies'
            },
            {
              label: 'Item 1.2.2',
              faIcon: 'fas fa-ambulance',
              items: [
                {
                  label: 'Item 1.2.2.1',
                  link: 'item-1-2-2-1',
                  faIcon: 'fas fa-anchor'
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      label: 'Item 2',
      icon: 'alarm',
      items: [
        {
          label: 'Item 2.1',
          link: '/item-2-1',
          icon: 'favorite'
        },
        {
          label: 'Item 2.2',
          link: '/item-2-2',
          icon: 'favorite_border'
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      label: 'Item 3',
      link: '/item-3',
      icon: 'offline_pin'
    },
    {
      label: 'Item 4',
      link: '/item-4',
      icon: 'star_rate',
    }
  ];

  config = {
    paddingAtStart: true,
    classname: 'my-custom-class',
    listBackgroundColor: 'rgb(208, 241, 239)',
    fontColor: 'rgb(8, 54, 71)',
    backgroundColor: 'rgb(208, 241, 239)',
    selectedListFontColor: 'red',
  };


  constructor() { }

  selectedItem($event: any) {
    console.log($event);
  }

 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Good evening Sir.
Take a look what Console says.
[image]

I am not so good on Angular too! but it looks like the imported module has missing provider for its own service. Can be bug or versions incapability.

But it can be very easy fixed.
All you have to do is add your own custom provider on your `AppModule` in `providers` properties

... see below

```
providers: [
   {provide:MultilevelMenuService,useClass:MultilevelMenuService}
],
```